# protobufjs: "Any" usage

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to define a Generic message using protobuffer:

```
message Generic {
  Header header = 1;
  google.protobuf.Any body = 2;
}
```

Let's say that the type of `body` for the decoding will be decided depending on what's inside the `header` block. For this example, with might choose `LoginReq`:

```
message LoginReq{
  string username=1;
  string password=2;
}
```

This is what I'm doing in my client:

```
function login() {
  var header = { reqId: 1 };
  var body = {
    username: "abcd",
    password: "1234",
  };
  var bodyReq = protos.LoginReqBody.create(body);
  var loginRequest = protos.Generic.create({ header, body: bodyReq });
  var buffer = protos.Generic.encode(loginRequest).finish();
  //and send it to the server...
}
```

When the message arrives to the server, anyway, just the `header` part is populated. Why?

Comment: Have you tried using `Any.pack` on `bodyReq` when including it in the call to `Generic.create`? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#any

Comment: How to import "Any" class in javascript?

Comment: Looks like there's an example here: https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/435

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar scenario recently, you might need to serialize/desearialize the content of "Any" within the "value" property.

For serialization layer, [any mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68450132) can work as long as you use consistent mechanism on both server and client side.

Luckily for us, protobufjs-cli generated classes already have serialization methods we can use, but you can use anything really, such as NodeJS v8 serialization.

In your example, something like this should work to create the message:

```
const loginRequest = protos.Generic.create({
  header, 
  body: {
    type_url: body.constructor.name,
    value: protos.LoginReqBody.encode(body).finish(),
  },
});

var buffer = protos.Generic.encode(loginRequest).finish();
//and send it to the server...
```

Then deserialize server side:

```
let loginRequest = ... //get your incoming loginRequest 
let bodyProto = protos.LoginReqBody.decode(loginRequest?.body?.value as Uint8Array);
```

Here `bodyProto` object is already an instance of `protos.LoginReqBody`.

If your body may receive any other type of value in the `Any` body, you may manually use the `type_url` property to help identifying which type you need to decode to.